# How to limit terminal output of a bash command in a script

Tags: linux, bash

(EDIT)
**I am creating a bash program that has many fully featured options as a networking program written in python. In my program, I am using the below command and it's specific output will be used as a variable.**

I am looking for a command or method to display only specific terminal output of a command. For example if, in my script, I use the command:

```
    iwconfig wlan0
```

Yet all I wish to see from this command is what mode in which wlan0 is set. (i.e. Master, Managed, Monitor, etc.)

I have looked and searched all over Google and Bash specific sites and cannot find a solution. I may be overlooking something.

Comment: I can pipe to grep, yes, but I am not familiar with grep so I do not know the syntax in which to show specific data from the full output of the initial command. As I said I am new to linux and I have only begun to self-teach scripting in bash so using other commands/tools in order to complete a task I seek is a bit beyond my ability at this point in time. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Maybe `iwconfig wlan0 | grep -Ei 'Master|Managed|Monitor|Mode'` to look for the words 'master', 'managed', 'monitor' or 'mode' in the output, using case-sensitive comparisons (and extended regular expressions).  See [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)
for POSIX's view on how `grep` works; see `man grep` or `info grep` or `grep --help` for your system's view on how `grep` works.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. That printed out the target line I seek to see. Yet if my interface is set to monitor mode, it prints everything after, "Mode: Monitor" Does grep have options to stop printing output after a desired pattern has been discovered or after the "mode" has been printed? Or do I have to deal with having the entire line printed? Either way it is fine. I have been studying the grep man information and I feel like I am reading a foreign language. I will keep testing with different grep options and see what I can figure out. Thanks again.

Comment: Since this question is about Linux, not programming, it would be more appropriate on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). Stack Overflow is intended only for programming questions.

Comment: My apologies. I believed bash to be a shell programming language.

Comment: @Yokai: since the question involves a pipeline, it is a shell programming question in my book — at least as appropriate here as elsewhere.  This has been a long time issue, and a complex one; where should a question such as this be asked?  Stack Overflow, SuperUser, Unix&Linux, Ubuntu, Ask Different (Apple), could all be valid.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - The answer to the OP's question involves finding the right `grep` option. When people come to a Stack Exchange site looking for help with `grep`, are they going to check Stack Overflow first, or SuperUser? I'll go ahead and answer his question here, but I still think it would be better at SuperUser, and/or possibly at Unix&Linux as well.

Comment: @rmunn: they'll come to SO first, and maybe later look elsewhere.

Comment: @rmunn **The fact that I ask because this is an important question related to my bash programming means that it is ON TOPIC. So I would appreciate if you would remove the "off topic" marks for this question. The question has been edited to reflect that is it related to programming in bash. Please fix it.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `grep` option you're looking for is `-o`, or `--only-matching` in its long form. It outputs *only* text that matches the search you gave it, and nothing else. For example:

```
iwconfig wlan0 | grep -o 'Mode:[^ ]*'
```

outputs `Mode:Managed` on my machine. The single quotes are necessary so that the shell won't try to interpret the `[`, `]` and `*` characters (with double quotes, if you happened to have a file with precisely the wrong name in your current directory, the shell might wrongly expand your parameter to the name of that file). The regular expression inside the single quotes means "the text `Mode:`, followed by any number of non-space characters", which is exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: @Yokai - In that case, I suggest you accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it; that will make it show up in a different color in any search that someone does later, so they will know that this question had an answer that solved the problem.

Comment: Done and done. Thank you again!

Comment: I have updated the question to be more relevant to programming so it is no longer off-topic.